# Zabbix Upgrade - Database upgrade failed

Tags: mysql, sql, zabbix

*EDIT : I should have created this post on ServerFault, wrong tab, sorry.*

I'm trying to upgrade my Zabbix Server today (MySQL DB).
Current version is 2.4.8, I want to update it to 3.4.4

Installation went well. When I start the zabbix-server process, the database starts upgrading, and it then stops with the following error message :

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1034] Incorrect key file for table 'alerts'; try to repair it [alter table alerts add p_eventid bigint unsigned]
```

So, I stopped zabbix-server, did the "alter table alerts add p_eventid bigint unsigned", restarted zabbix-server, and now got this error message :

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1060] Duplicate column name 'p_eventid' [alter table alerts add p_eventid bigint unsigned]
```

Which is a bit troubling for me, as the error message is different, but the proposed solution is still the same, and has been done already.

I did some research, found out [this ZBX bug report](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-11381) that can be useful but I have no idea how to apply the workaround, as I'm no expert in SQL. As far as I can tell, I have a missing index in the alerts table (alerts_7). I tried to create it with the following command, after googling a bit :

```
create INDEX on alerts (p_eventid) USING BTREE;
```

Still got an error (the second one).

Anyone had that situation already, and found out how to solve it ?

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question, so you'll get a much better answer (likely) on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/.

I'd also **strongly** recommend including information about how you performed the upgrade.  If you're running on Ubuntu (for example), include the commands you used (was it via official `apt`repositories?  Etc.)

Good luck - I've used Zabbix for years and found the upgrade paths very reliable on Debian.  You might want to try upgrading to sub-versions in multiple passes (just a suggestion).

Comment: @wally : you're totally right, I had 2 tabs opened, one here, one on SF, and created the question in the wrong tab, it has been a long day, my bad. 

My setup is pretty simple, I have the zabbix server on one vm, the DB on another one. I've created a new clean VM, Ubuntu 16.04 on it, and installed Zabbix through the packages. Shutted down the old zabbix vm, started the new one, started the process, and the DB upgrade started with the errors mentioned in my original post.

Comment: @SBO no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had some time to work on this, the problem was that the tmp directory was too small for the upgrade operation. After changing the tmp path in the my.cnf, and restarting the upgrade, everything worked as expected !

Answer (score 2):

`[Z3005] query failed: [1060] Duplicate column name 'p_eventid' [alter table alerts add p_eventid bigint unsigned]` means that the upgrade script is trying to add a column to the `alerts` table but a column with that name currently exists! (Probably from a previously failed attempt at upgrade)

You need to mitigate all other issues that caused it to fail in the first place and then drop that column with

`alter table alerts drop p_eventid;`

and try running `zabbix_server` again to retry the database upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The part in the square brackets was not a suggestion, it was the command that was attempted. Now it fails because the column already exists.

In this case, it might be enough to drop that column and start Zabbix server again. Make sure to have database backup before you even started the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I thought it was a recommandation, my bad ! Will try it again tomorrow and let you know.